# How to view image on google maps marker from URL?

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, google-maps-markers, android-glide

Here I am using this approach to view image on Google Map marker, I am facing "Image Buffer is not an array Error".

Here this is code of My Marker

```
 mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snippet)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("https://c.ndtvimg.com/2019-10/5cnigl7_virat-kohli-afp_625x300_15_October_19.jpg"))));
```

& this is how I load image from URL to bitmap Using Glide

```
private Bitmap bitmap;

 private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url){

        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(25,25) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                        bitmap =resource;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                    }
                });
        return bitmap;
    }
```

this is error got while debugging

```
Unexpected Error: Image buffer is not an array.
```

If any other better approach please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the bitmap you fetching using Glide is finish loading after you returned bitmap. Glide load image asynchronously but you return bitmap immediately.

Please give a try with the code below.

```
private void getMarkerFromURL(String url){
            Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(url)
                    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>(25,25) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                            mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                            .title(title)
                            .snippet(snippet)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
                        }
                    });
        }
```